# System.ArgumentNullException after switching Frames (Windows Store App)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps

I wanted to make simple navigation with passing data between two frames in *Windows Store App*.

When i start from MainPage, navigating to BlankPage

```
 private void goTo_BlankPage()
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage),multimedia);
    }
```

And then i use BackButton:

```
<Button x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"/>
```

Everything goes fine.

But when i add:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e){}
```

to BlankPage (so i can handle passed data), and then try to go back from it, i'm getting `System.ArgumentNullException`.

What may be wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

Call `base.OnNavigatedTo` in the overriden `OnNavigatedTo` method.

App must be doing something in the base method which it might be needing in case of going back

Comment: i knew that there probably is 1-line solution for that xD
thanks, that worked perfectly :)